# how to compare more than one column from two different tables of database and update, if it match the same record in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I want to update data of column **completed** after comparing the data of two columns **employee_id & job_id** from each of the tables `resignation` and `request`. What code do need to write in my laravel controller.

```
*request table:.*
| ID   | employee_id  | job_id | completed |
| ---- | ------------ |--------|-----------|
| 1    | 1            | 1      | 1         |
| 2    | 2            | 4      | 0         |
| 3    | 3            | 7      | 0         |
| 4    | 1            | 6      | 0         |

*resignation table:.*
| ID   | employee_id  | job_id | action    |
| ---- | ------------ |--------|-----------|
| 1    | 1            | 1      | 1         |
| 2    | 1            | 6      | 0         |
| 3    | 2            | 9      | 0         |
```

I have written the below code in my controller but it is not working.

```
    DB::table('request as q')
        ->leftJoin('employee as e','q.employee_id','=','e.ID')
        ->leftJoin('resignation as r','e.ID','=','r.employee_id')
        ->where('r.ID',$ID)->where('r.job_id','=','q.job_id')
        ->update([ 'q.completed' => '1' ]);
```

Comment: Your code looks fine do you have specific question to ask

Comment: I also feel my code is fine but it is not updating any record as i want. I actually want to match both column employee_id, job_id of both table for specific condition and then update completed with 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with below code.

```
DB::table('request')
        ->join('resignation', function ($join) {
            $join->on('request.employee_id', '=', 'resignation.employee_id');
            $join->on('request.job_id', '=', 'resignation.job_id');
        })
        ->where('resignation.ID', '=', $ID)
        ->update([ 'request.completed' => '1' ]);
```